# Load Content after specific time by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get data from database without reloading. So I did this

[Code In PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/bbGc1qxu)

after doing that this is the ajax part for click

```
    
    function ed_action(p_authority_id, ed_value) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "inc/ed_action.php",
            data: 'p_authority_id='+ encodeURIComponent(p_authority_id) + '&ed_value='+ encodeURIComponent(ed_value),
            success: function(data) {
                if(data){
                    $("#show").html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

this is the ed_action.php file

```
$func = new functions();

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $ed_value = $_POST['ed_value'];
    $p_authority_id = $_POST['p_authority_id'];

    $user_data = array(
        'ed_action'   => $ed_value
    );

    $where_cond = array(
        'where' => array('p_authority_id' => $p_authority_id),
        'cross_check' => 'and',
        'return_type' => 'single'
    );
    $table_name = 'p_authrity_user';

    $update = $func->update($table_name, $user_data, $where_cond);
    $ed_action_data = $func->select($table_name, $where_cond);
}
```

I successfully retrive the data by click. But Now I want when I click on the enable button it will show the disable button without reloading and when click on disable, it should be show the enable button. so what should I do?

Please can you help me?

Comment: you could put both buttons into the html, but the disable button you hide with css. When you click on enable button, hide enable button and show disable button with javascript/jquery. same with disable button.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. i tried with that but can i do this with ajax?

Comment: you can call a function that hides/shows those elements in the success callback of the ajax

Comment: how to do that ?? can you help me out

Comment: i have to do some work atm, i will give you an example in about an hour if nobody else has provided an answer until then

Comment: ya sure. No Problem man. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments: In your success function of the ajax request you can just toggle the visibilty of the two buttons.

```
function ed_action(p_authority_id, ed_value) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "inc/ed_action.php",
        data: 'p_authority_id='+ encodeURIComponent(p_authority_id) + '&ed_value='+ encodeURIComponent(ed_value),
        success: function(data) {
            if(data){
                $("#show").html(data);
                toggleButtons();
            }
        }
    });
}

function toggleButtons(){
    var enableBtn = $('button.ed_action.ed_action_enable'); // add class ed_action_enable to button so you can get it here
    var disableBtn = $('button.ed_action.ed_action_disable'); // add class ed_action_disable to button so you can get it here

    enableBtn.toggle(); // toggles visibility of element
    disableBtn.toggle(); // toggles visibility of element

    /* shorter code for this:
    $('button.ed_action.ed_action_enable').toggle;
    $('button.ed_action.ed_action_disable').toggle;
    */
}
```

For this to work you would need to

1: output both buttons into the html (disable btn hidden)

2: add one more class to the buttons so you can get them easily with jquery

Comment: you forgot to add the class ed_action_disable

Comment: sorry for that. but same thing happens

Comment: if then it still 'doesnot show anything' you can debug with alerts to find out what the error might be. I will call it a day now, have a nice WE

Comment: my suspicion is that ajax success is not fired, or that there is no received data in success function, cheers